# gif image is not loading in firefox and chrome

Tags: image, gif

We have to load a gif image in website. It is loading perfectly in Safari and not in the Firefox and Chrome.

Getting an error message only in firefox and chrome like below.

> The image sample.gif cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

Comment: Yes, it may contain error. Double check / Re-save it with Image software

Comment: but why is it loading in safari?